# Efficient way of simplifying parts of a dataframe column with above values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, logic

The problem consists in changing sequences of numbers between zeros, to the first value of the specific sequence.

Example:

| Input(df['p']) | Desired Output(df['Do']) |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 |
| 115 | 115 |
| 090 | 115 |
| 0 | 0 |
| -80 | -80 |
| -90 | -80 |
| -70 | -80 |
| 0 | 0 |

I have tried using np.where, and logic to find the numbers that must be changed, though i'm not able to scale this solution. It only works for one row.

Example:

```
                  #check a change in value   #eliminate the first change from zero   #assigning the above p value
df['A'] =np.where(df['p']!=df['p'].shift(1),np.where(df['p'].shift(1)==0,df['p'],df['p'].shift(1)),df['p'])
```

| Input(df['p']) | Actual Output(df['A']) |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 |
| 115 | 115 |
| 090 | 115 |
| 0 | 0 |
| -80 | -80 |
| -90 | -80 |
| -70 | -90 |
| 0 | 0 |

Something like that should work, but np.where doesn't support iterations between the same column.

```
                  #check a change in value   #eliminate the first change from zero   #assigning the above Do value
   #\/                                                                                 \/
df['Do'] = np.where(df['p']!=df['p'].shift(1),np.where(df['p'].shift(1)==0,df['p'],df['Do'].shift(1)),df['p'])
```

Tks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you want are the rows not equal (`ne`) to 0 and where the previous row (with `shift`) is not 0 either. Then [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) the values for these rows and `ffill` to propagate the previous not 0 value

```
#input
df = pd.DataFrame({'p':[0,0,0,115,90,0,-80,-90,-70,0]})

# get the result
df['res'] = df['p'].mask(df['p'].ne(0) & df['p'].shift().ne(0)).ffill()

print(df)
     p    res
0    0    0.0
1    0    0.0
2    0    0.0
3  115  115.0
4   90  115.0
5    0    0.0
6  -80  -80.0
7  -90  -80.0
8  -70  -80.0
9    0    0.0
```

or you can check only once `ne` to 0 and use the `shift` after

```
m = df['p'].ne(0)
df['res'] = df['p'].mask(m & m.shift()).ffill()
```